# AWS Lambda internal node module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-request

As far as I know, there are node modules that are automatically installed by AWS Lambda.

**Is it excluded if you know that the module included a [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module?**

If anyone knows about this part, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: there are certain/standard pre-built node modules that will be available in aws for nodejs and not all. Request module should be available foe use. Have you tried it ?

Comment: I used it assuming that the request module is built-in, but an error appears as Cannot find module "request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` module is not installed by default, only NodeJS `standard libraries` and `aws-sdk` are installed by default and the rest of modules will originate from either your lambda layers or the lambda function's `node_modules`. You can find more details from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then have you ever had a request module built in?

Comment: @JunseokLee I'd propose to use the standard `https` library from nodejs standard library bro. just make a bunch of shared functions for this purpose!